# Protecting config file of web hosting

Tags: php, passwords, config, credentials, hardcoded

I have recently done security audit of my website coded in php.
Security audit report has suggested not save hard-coded credentials in config file on web hosting.

How can i store it at some other place for protecting it

Comment: By moving it outside the section of the server side file system that is published by the http server.

Comment: Flagged as needing more clarity: How are you currently storing your credentials? Do you have access to a framework (like Symfony where you can use .env and secrets)? Do you you have an automated build pipeline. There's just simply too many ways this can go without clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Determine what your case.
Many way to protect the configurations files, depending of your requirements.

**But - NO SYSTEM IS SAFE**

When you have custom code (*eg: not to use such a full framework*) that you created custom config files.
You could include outside of your public directory on **web hosting panel** / public root directory.

Depending on shared hosting use apache (based) as their web server,
you could use *.htaccess* to set important environment, for example:

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv APP_ENVIRONMENT production
SetEnv DB_NAME database_name
SetEnv DB_PASS database_password
</IfModule>
```

And the other one is, make your files hidden and disable access / forbid the dot file, eg:

```
.config.php
.configuration.php
.any-file-name-here.php
```

and disable access to all hidden files on htaccess file.

```
# Deny access to hidden files - files that start with a dot (.)
<FilesMatch "^\.">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Back to It depends on your needs.
Configuration files can be safe as long as you do your best to keep your code as bug-free as possible.